# Users, Customers, Tenants, Employees - All in the same table?

Tags: database, structure, multi-tenant

In this case let me be more specific about the problem

I've got a peoples table(with customer & supplier) and I've got a users table(for users who can login).

Currently I have this DB structure

Customers -> Organisations -> linked through rel_customer_addresses to address table.
(as 1 customer could have delivery_address, invoice address etc.)

Users -> Tenants -> linked through rel_users_addresses to the address table 
(as 1 user could have delivery_address, invoice address etc.)

Now I've got in the invoice table customer_key. The problem is when the user himself is the customer and the invoice is from one of his customers. How do I indicate my web app to look up user and not the customer?

Comment: It really just depends on how much data you will be storing for each task. The rule of thumb is use only what you need, but you also do not want one large, hard to use database.

Comment: FYI this question is open-ended. This site is mostly Q and A style for specific programming questions. They'll downvote you out if you aren't careful. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the post. I've rewritten my post to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking at 2 separate entities (customers and users), I would go ahead and use 2 separate tables and have them share a unique identifier (i.e., username, SID).

That way there's no chance of one seeing information from the other without the appropriate permissions.

There are several ways to control this, but the logic is something like this.

`If userID exists in table user, do this.`
`If userID exists in table customer, do this.`
`If userID exists in table user AND table customer, do this.`

That way you can control the situation completely either independently or together. In other words, you could grant special permissions to `userID` that is found in table `customer`, or just make it completely separate (similar to say, how facebook makes a separate 'identity' for pages vs the account it's registered to).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Again, 

Thanks for the help. I went with the approach using roles and put all user types in one table. This was the easierst, because at some point I needed to let all user types login and them being now in the users table makes everything easier.